# Faces twists. Bridges Edges Loops Problem

Tags: edges, faces

I’m a beginner and I’m following a lesson on internet, the problem is when I’m trying to create a faces between selected edges, my faces twists..
How can I solve it ? I’ve been stuck for hours now ahah I don’t know what I did wrong

[image: Edges selected]
[image: Face twists]

Thank you so much for your help !

Comment: Most likely there is inverted normals or doubled vertices in your model.

Comment: Oh thank you so much!!! Actually it was inverted normals ! Thanks a lot